# Bayes' Theorem and Agresti-Coull: Will it blend?

Tags: bayesian, python, approximation, uncertainty

I'd like to use Bayes' Theorem on data obtained through a small random sample, and I want to use Agresti-Coull (or any other alternative technique) to know how big the uncertainty is.

Here is Bayes' Theorem:

$P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)\cdot P(A)}{P(B)}$

Now, all the data I have on this system is obtained from small random samples, so there's a large uncertainty involved with all three variables, $P(B|A)$, $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

I've been using Agresti-Coull to obtain both the value and the uncertainty for each of these three variables. (I represent the `number+-uncertainty` as a [`ufloat`](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/#an-easy-to-use-calculator) object using the [`uncertainties`](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/) package.)

But using Agresti-Coull three times separately for these three variables is a problem; They are dependent on each other. So I've been getting impossible results. For example, if you let $P(B)$'s uncertainty pull it downward, and the respective uncertainties of $P(B|A)$ and $P(A)$ pull them upwards, you get a total probability bigger than one.

Is there a way to do Agresti-Coull-style approximation on the whole Bayes expression instead of doing it on the three pieces separately?

Comment: As I understand the [Agresti-Coull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval) procedure is used to generate approximate confidence intervals for the binomial proportion confidence interval. I am not sure I see the relationship to Bayes theorem. Could you provide some context and your goals within the context to understand how the bayes arises in the context of the Agresti-Coull method?

Comment: @cool-RR: How exactly are you estimating those three probabilities?

Comment: @whuber: For $P(A)$ I check how many of the messages in my finite sample have $A$, and divide that by the size of the sample. For $P(B|A)$ I check how many of the messages that have $A$ also have $B$, and divide that by the number of messages that have $A$. etc.

Comment: @cool-RR: why don't you just estimate P(A|B) directly, then, as the fraction of B samples that are also A?

Comment: @Srikant: Agresti-Coull lets you draw conclusion about the true proportion from a small finite sample, and gives you a confidence interval with an answer. I have a similar situation: I have a small finite sample and I want to get the value of $P(A|B)$ along with a confidence interval. To give more context: I'm developing something like a Bayesian spam filter, and this is the probability that a message is spam given that it has a certain word.

Comment: Wow @whuber, you blew my mind. I have no idea why I've been doing this. I got the impression this is what people do on Bayesian spam filters, so that's what I've been doing. ($P(A|B)$ is the probability a message is spam given that it contains a certain word, for example 'cheese'.) Now I tried to simply calculate $P(A|B)$ directly, and it seems to work, so I don't even need the answer to this question. Unless I'm missing something. Maybe you have an idea why people use Bayes' Theorem in Bayesian spam filtering when filtering by a single word like this?

Comment: @cool-RR: Just a small technical remark, to make things precise: the factory *function* `ufloat()` creates a `UFloat` *object*.  Case does matter, here (the two names were chosen to be close to each other on purpose).  :)

Answer (score 5):

When applying the formula for P(B|A) for [Agresti-Coull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval), it seems important to me to use, for the denominator (ñ), a number with uncertainty.  The formula ñ=P(A)*N+4 (where N is the size of your sample) gives you this number, after you calculate P(A) with an uncertainty.  With the [uncertainties package](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/), this would be:

```
# Calculation of P(A):
P_A = ufloat(…, …)
# Calculation of P(B|A):
P_B_A = …/(P_A*N+4)
```

Thus, P(B|A) is automatically correlated to P(A).

Furthermore, you must make sure that you feed `ufloat()` with *standard deviations*.  This mean using a particular z_{1-alpha/2} value, in the Agresti-Coull formula.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing out how to do this with the uncertainties package.

Answer (score 3):

[Error propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_propagation) won't work in the way handled by the uncertainties package.  As you note, they're dependent, so you have to take the covariances into account.

You can obtain the variance of your distribution P(B|A) using the [Delta Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method) and use that to obtain a confidence interval.

With Bayesian inference, you might find it simpler to use a [credible interval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Credible_interval).  The following slides do a good job of explaining how to obtain this:

- [Bayesian analysis of one, two, and n-parameter models](http://home.uchicago.edu/~grynav/bayes/ABSLec5.ppt)
- [A Brief Tutorial on Bayesian Thinking](http://bayes.bgsu.edu/nsf_web/tutorial/a_brief_tutorial.htm)

Comment: The uncertainties package does apply error propagation theory (it was created just for that), *and* can take covariances as an input (http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/user_guide.html#correlated-variables). :)

Answer (score 2):

[Brown, Cai, and DasGupta, AS, 2002](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-statistics/volume-30/issue-1/Confidence-Intervals-for-a-binomial-proportion-and-asymptotic-expansions/10.1214/aos/1015362189.full)

[Brown, Cai, and DasGupta, Stat Sci, 2001](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/statistical-science/volume-16/issue-2/Interval-Estimation-for-a-Binomial-Proportion/10.1214/ss/1009213286.full)

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but in my knowledge the above two papers are the most cited ones recently when it comes to binomial proportions' CI and estimation.

Sorry if this is not what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

This is a potential answer to the title of the original question and not necessarily the body of the question...

Looking at the Agresti confidence interval measurement, to my eyes it bears a resemblance to a Bayesian estimator.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval#Agresti-Coull_Interval

Looking at p = 1/n * ( X + 1/2 * z^2), I suspect the 1/2 could be considered Bayesian prior knowledge.

Let’s say for example, that one conducts a congressional approval poll and historically those polls have an approval rating of 0.35.  Using a Bayesian train of thought perhaps one could use that information as prior knowledge and feed it in by using 0.35 instead of the 1/2 coefficient?

I suspect one could do so successfully.